# Разность между меньшим временем и большим должна быть со знаком минус

Tags: python, datetime

Подскажите пожалуйста... Суть заключается в том, что в python3 необходимо узнать разность между фактическим временем, точней, неким интервалом (сколько пользователь работал с делом) и нормой времени (тоже интервал). Если фактическое больше нормы, то результат должен быть со знаком минус. Если отнимаешь от 00:30:00 00:36:42, то результат -1 day, 23:53:18, а нужно, чтоб был -0:06:42. Как этого добиться?

Comment: В каком виде у вас время хранится?

Comment: Формат отображения timedelta, увы, таков - и это описано в документации. https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html *String representations of timedelta objects are normalized similarly to their internal representation. This leads to somewhat unusual results for negative timedeltas.* Вычитай из бОльшего меньшее, а потом, если нужно, добавляй впереди минус...

Comment: @Эникейщик берётся из базы, в базе тип interval, а в python, похоже, datetime.timedelta. Потому что print выдаёт datetime.timedelta(0, 2202), datetime.timedelta(0, 1800). Но, как уже подсказали, надо отнимать и ставить минус впереди.

Comment: Видимо тогда проще на -1 умножать, когда требуется.

Comment: @Эникейщик Умножение на минус единицу снова приведёт к некорректному с точки зрения автора выводу.

Answer (score 0):

Результат уже правильный. Вас смущает текстовое представление `datetime.timedelta` объекта по умолчанию:

```
>>> import datetime as DT
>>> a = DT.timedelta(minutes=30)
>>> b = DT.timedelta(minutes=36, seconds=42)
>>> a < b
True
>>> a - b
datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=85998)
```

Это представление показывает как значения внутри хранятся: [секунды и микросекунды всегда положительны](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta). В виде строки в зависимости от задачи разные форматы можно использовать:

```
>>> "-" * (a < b) + str(abs(a - b))
'-0:06:42'
```

Это то же значение, по другому отформатированное.